# Drill Down in Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am building a web app and am looking to convert the UI to use Knockout JS. I am a total noob in Knockout so please be kind!

Normally I would load an employee list (using PHP) and then if an employee is selected I would find the ID of that employee using JQuery and then make and AJAX call to my backend, fill in the result box and slide it down.

Is there a way to replicate this behavior in Knockout?

Comment: Yes, I do have the non knockout version of the code.  However I would like to clean up the code by removing all of the PHP.  I have been through all of the tutorials.  They were awesome!  So basically my question is how do I get the ID of the selected employee so I can drill into them.  I have done more reading but still have not found the answer to that one.

Comment: Nathan, the reason I asked for that stuff wasn't to give you a hard time (ok, maybe the last one was). It's because answering your question with such limited detail is very difficult. What do you mean by "selected"? What does your result box look like? What does your employee class or list look like? How can anyone help you when you haven't described your problem well enough to understand what you want?

Comment: Thanks Tyrsius, the problem always seems totally clear to me. :-)  I agree that this one is a little vague.

Answer (score 1):

The way to handle ajax drill downs in knockout/jquery is to use the knockout click handlers.  This allows you to then pull any attribute or the item itself and then process the ajax in jquery.  Example from my code below.

In the html file:

```
...
<div class="empListName" data-bind="text: fullName(), click: $root.showEmp">
</div>
....
```

In the js file:

```
function MainScreenViewModel() {
  // Data
  var self = this;
  self.employees = ko.observableArray([]);
  ...

  // Functions
  self.showEmp = function(data, event){
    var id = data.empId();
    var checkA = $(event.target).parent().find('.empListNameX').first();
    var expand = $(event.target).parent().next();
    if (checkA.hasClass('open')){ //Close it
        checkA.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
        expand.slideUp();
    }else{
        $.get('/employee/getempinfo/'+id, function(info){
            checkA.addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
            expand.html(info).slideDown();
        })
    }
  }
  ...
}
```